# How to intercept middle-click paste event in Linux?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, mouseevent, ubuntu-18.04

I'm looking for a way to intercept middle-click Paste event in Ubuntu linux.

I want to show a popup menu whenever user tries to paste text into a text box, address bar, etc using the middle click of mouse (also preventing the default behaviour).

I am hopefully looking for a solution that will work with Ubuntu/Gnome but a general purpose solution would be great.

**It's important that I do not want to intercept all middle-click events (i.e. closing tabs, etc) but only when the middle click is on any things that can accept text input / paste.**

Also I don't mind if it is python or C or even a utility program - as long as I can figure out how it is done, I can port the code myself.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it's ubuntu specific check [this thread from askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4507/how-do-i-disable-middle-mouse-button-click-paste).

Comment: @metatoaster This could be useful and a step in the right direction. Thanks for your insightful comment